# Newline ("\n") before output in bash

Tags: bash, prompt, output

I want to modify my output in bash for better view of output. Simply put `\n` before this. How can I change it in `.bashrc`? For example:

It's default:

```
root@comp:$ abc
bash: abc: command not found
```

I want this:

```
root@comp:$ abc

bash: abc: command not found
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `trap` the `DEBUG` signal:

```
trap 'printf "\n"' DEBUG
```

`DEBUG` trapped command `printf "\n"` will be run before the command is executed unlike `PROMPT_COMMAND` which will be run after the command is executed.

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent.

**Example:**

```
$ abc
No command 'abc' found, did you mean:
....
$ trap 'printf "\n"' DEBUG
$ abc

No command 'abc' found, did you mean:
....
```